# Windows registry -- list of subkeys

Tags: java, registry

I need to list the names of Windows registry **subkeys**, located in the section -

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ Tcpip \ Parameters \ Interfaces **

For example, I have this are -

```
{138CB222-111B-4B51-80C9-88F9D69FB4B8}

{2BC51B32-5C8A-425D-9EB9-21FF787A2632}

{5D5FF183-9213-40AE-9E43-89F5F6DA6161}

{A2E02E9B-7262-45D1-88B2-D9B0C21763F9}

{A8427644-D51A-4D73-922D-BEA2FB68F663}
```

Ie they are located -

```
+-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
|
|-SYSTEM
| |
.. -CurrentControlSet
    |   
    |-Services
    | |
   ... -Tcpip
        |
        |-Parameters
       ...|
          |-Interfaces
          | |
         ...|+{138CB222-111B-4B51-80C9-88F9D69FB4B8}
            |+{2BC51B32-5C8A-425D-9EB9-21FF787A2632}
            |+{5D5FF183-9213-40AE-9E43-89F5F6DA6161}
            |+{A2E02E9B-7262-45D1-88B2-D9B0C21763F9}
            |+{A8427644-D51A-4D73-922D-BEA2FB68F663}
           ...
```

How to realize a list of subkeys in Java?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to enumerate keys using JNA library. See  [RegEnumKeyEx](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32.html#RegEnumKeyEx%28com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY,%20int,%20char%5B%5D,%20com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference,%20com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference,%20char%5B%5D,%20com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference,%20com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.FILETIME%29) -